# qgis plugin using python

Tags: python, plugins, qgis

I'm trying to code a qgis plugin using the latest version of python and qgis 2.18 but I keep getting this error message:

`AttributeError: AutomatisationDEPLOIEMENT instance has no attribute 'utilisat_lineEdit'`

This is my code would anyone kindly help me?

```
class AutomatisationDEPLOIEMENT:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgisInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'AutomatisationDEPLOIEMENT_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)


        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Automatisation DEPLOIEMENT')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'AutomatisationDEPLOIEMENT')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'AutomatisationDEPLOIEMENT')
```

... snip ...

```
def loginCheck(self):
    username = self.utilisat_lineEdit.text()
    password = self.pass_lineEdit.text()

    connection = sqlite3.connect("login.db")
    result = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?", (username, password))
    if (len(result.fetchall()) > 0):
        print("User Found ! ")
    else:
        print("User Not Found !")
        self.showMessageBox('Warning', 'Invalid Username And Password')
    connection.close()
```

I'm trying to get the logincheck function to work

Comment: To use python 3 you need to use Qgis 3.x, for python 2 you can use Qgis 2.x but it is out of support now.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly shows what you did wrong:
`AttributeError: AutomatisationDEPLOIEMENT instance has no attribute 'utilisat_lineEdit'`

In the first line of your `loginCheck()` you are trying to access `self.utilisat_lineEdit` but this property does not exist. I guess your are trying to access some kind of gui element, but this is not available in your class.

Comment: yes but that element exists in my ui dialog but the class doesn't recognize it .. how do i make that element available in my class ?

Comment: Call the instance of the gui class and access it from there? You didn't post any code that shows how you create/store your GUI instances. I can't help you without further information.

Comment: i created the inerface using qt designer and the ui file is storted in the qgis plugin folder alongside the py file that qgis generates when u creat the plugin. i'm currently editing the py file

Comment: I think you are missing some basic knowledge regarding classes, instances and references. Somewhere in your Code you instantiate your GUI class and assign it some variable. One way to access this instance in another class is to refer this variable in the constructor of the other class (your ```__init__()``` method) and then save the reference to a property of that class. Please read some tutorial if you don't know what I am talking about.